# How to avoid frequent location updates?

Tags: android, gps

I am new to android. I want to get GPS locations at an interval of 3 minutes, but I'm getting location updates on every second.

How can I avoid this?

Please suggest something. I'm using the following code:

```
captureFrequencey=3*60*1000;    
LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, captureFrequencey, 0, this);
```

Comment: You should post more code, it's hard to say anything based on this snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, captureFrequencey, 0, this);
```

Thats because you set the minimum distance to 0. Change it to 100 meters and check!

```
LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, captureFrequencey, 100, this);
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I have changed minimum distance to 100.

Comment: Glad it helps! Please accept it as an answer when it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy Ninja has already given you the solution.
But you should understand that, when you call request location updates it checks for conditions min time & min dist and if anyone is true it catches the location. In your code

```
LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                                                captureFrequencey, 0, this);
```

you have mentioned 0 as min distance, this condition is true all the time. So you are getting frequent location updates.
Hope this info helps u.

Comment: Thanks a lot sachin.surya89

Answer (score 0):

See the Location Strategies in [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick point to add to the correct answers provided... setting the update time & distance will not work exactly the same on all devices.

These parameters are treated as "hints" to the Location Provider.

So while it is good practice, some devices may not always obey these exact values.